# Gather columnames into a single column when a cell contains a value

Tags: excel

I want to return the text of the column name when a certain row contains a '1'.
The endresult should fill a single column, let's say Z.

So for example, when cell A2 contains a '1', I want to return the text in A1 to Z2; when A5 contains a '1', I want to return the text in A1 to Z5. The same for all other columns, so when cell B10 contains a '1', I want the text in B1 to show in Z10.

All rows contain just a single '1' , so there won't be a problem with overlapping values in column Z.

I looked into functions like `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `VLOOKUP` but have a hard time getting close to what I need...

Comment: So if A10 and B10 have 1 you want both A1 and B1 in Z10 or will it always only be one per row?  If one,  then INDEX/MATCH will do.  If more you will need TEXTJOIN() which is only available with Office 365 Excel.

Comment: Every row contains just one instance of '1'. So If A10 has a '1', There will be no other '1' in row 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Z2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$Y$1,MATCH(1,$A2:$Y2,0)),"No 1s")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! (as long as I replace the `,` with `;` for google spreadsheets :) )

Comment: the difference between `,` and `;` is local.  In the US we use `,` even in google sheets.  Also if this was for Google Sheets it should have been tagged as such.  But as it answered the question please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.